# Como insertar multiples valores de un checkbox en una tabla

Tags: php, mysql, array, checkbox

Como inserto un array de un checkbox en una tabla mysql

```
 [seleccionael25] => Array
    (
        [0] => Oximetros de pulso
        [1] => Linterna (Penlights)
        [2] => Repuestos Littmann
        [3] => Doppler fetal
        [4] => Martillo de refeljos
        [5] => Cubre-Fonendos
        [6] => Tensiometros
        [7] => Equipo de organos
        [8] => Otros accesorios
        [9] => Batas Greys Anatomy
    )
```

He usado estas estos codigos sin exito

```
Test1 $articulo = $_POST[ 'seleccionael25'][0] ."-". $_POST['seleccionael25'][1] ."-". $_POST['seleccionael25'][2] ."-". $_POST['seleccionael25'][3] ."-". $_POST['seleccionael25'][4] ."-". $_POST['seleccionael25'][5] ."-". $_POST['seleccionael25'][6] ."-". $_POST['seleccionael25'][7] ."-". $_POST['seleccionael25'][8] ."-". $_POST['seleccionael25'][9]; //no funciona

Test2 $articulo = $_POST[ 'seleccionael25'] //Inserta unicamente la palabra "array"

Test3 $articulo = implode(',', $_POST['seleccionael25']); //No me funciona

Test4 $checkbox = array("seleccionael25" => $_POST[seleccionael25]);// codigo obtenido en jotform
$articulo  = implode(',', $checkbox['seleccionael25']); //Test4
```

En el insert esta ok pero no inserta el array

```
$conexion->query( "INSERT INTO $tabla_db1 (pedido, seleccionael25, ......mas items) VALUES ('$pedido','$articulo', mas items)" );
```

Alguien me puede decir en que estoy fallando? realmente no doy con la solución
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20176673/how-do-i-insert-multiple-checkbox-values-into-a-table

Update: SOLUCION encontrada. el problema estaba en que el varchar tenia limite de 30 caracteres y cuando seleccionaba varios se pasaba del limite, aumente  el limite y listo

Comment: pon solo un ejemplo de código y la respuesta/error obtenida, de otra forma es muy difícil prestar ayuda.

Comment: por favor, si has resulto tu problema.
1) Postealo en la parte de "Respuesta" y no editando la pregunta.

2) Cierra la misma.

Saludos y gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solucion a mi pregunta esta en la linea de codigo TEST3 del enunciado del la pregunta obtenida de esta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20176673/how-do-i-insert-multiple-checkbox-values-into-a-table.
A mi no me funcionaba, era porque era porque la los caracteres asignados al varchar del campo eran menores al texto que estaba ingresando, por eso no insertaba nada. corregí de varchar 30 a 100 p ej y funciono

Answer (score 1):

Muy buenas. Creo que tengo el mismo problema que a ti, he investigado caleta sobre la situacion de los checkbox, aunque habian pequeñas partes de la soluciones en otras temas, como que actualmente en php 7 se le puede obtener los `$_POST` hay como dos opciones:

`$check_value = isset($_POST['mi_nombre_del_checkbox']) ? 1 : 0;`

Del PHP 7 `Null coalescing operator`

`$check_value = $_POST['mi_nombre_del_checkbox'] ?? 0;`

Además no te olvides que actualmente `MySql_*` está siendo despreciable, recomiendo usar PDO/MySqli, ver en este enlace:
[¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)

Espero que te haya ayudado, saludos!